# How to identify if the centroid point touches a line or not?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, intrusion-detection

I am working with an intrusion detection algorithm which works on the basis of line crossing detection. I have developed a basic algorithm using the equation y = mx+c, but it is showing some wrong detection when the person reaches nearer to the line. I need some suggestion for making it a perfect line touching algorithm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: in your example, do you want to know if the red dot is to the left of the green line? or if the red dot is precisely a point of the green line? if it is the second option, you will probably have to think of a thin rectangle and very small circle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Gustavo, I want to find whether the red dot precisely a point on the green line. Could you explain how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your line has starting and ending points `[x1, y1]` and `[x2, y2]`, then the line equation is:

`y - y1 = m * (x - x1)`, where `m = (y2 - y1)/(x2-x1)`

Then you can check if a point belongs to the line or not, substituting either `x` or `y`, and checking if the other matches the line equation.

In Pyhton:

```
# the two points that define the line
p1 = [1, 6]
p2 = [3, 2]

# extract x's and y's, just for an easy code reading
x1, y1 = p1
x2, y2 = p2

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)

# your centroid
centroid = [2,4]
x3, y3 = centroid

# check if centroid belongs to the line
if (m * (x3-x1) + y1) == y3:
    print("Centroid belongs to line")
```

#### But probably...

...you'll have better results calculating the distance between red dot and the line ([distance from a point to a line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)), and then checking if it is near enough (i.e. distance less than some value).

In Python:

```
# points that define the line
p1 = [1, 6]
p2 = [3, 2]
x1, y1 = p1
x2, y2 = p2

centroid = [2,4]
x3, y3 = centroid

# distance from centroid to line
import math # to calculate square root
dist = abs((y2-y1)*x3 - (x2-x1)*y3 + x2*y1 - y2*x1)/math.sqrt((y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2)

if dist < some_value:
    print("Near enough")
```

Comment: If you use the first solution, it's better to check before it the line is vertical (i.e. `if x1 == x2`). Treat this as a special case and just check if your centroid x is also equal to `x1`or `x2` (i.e `if x3 == x1`).

Comment: Actually I am using the second solution. I understood the case, I was testing that. I think for the vertical line and horizontal line as well it shows the same issue right?? Division by zero

Comment: using the code above, division by zero only appears when the line is vertical.

Comment: Also, if you want to use this to process frames of a live video, maybe you can increase performance by *not* using `sqrt`. Instead, you can use squared lenghts.

Comment: But Gustavo, now I have encountered a new issue which is even though the centroid is not touching the line it is creating an alarm. I have updated the issue with an image, you can see the dist threshold value as I have included that piece of code also in the screenshot

Comment: oh, yes... the solution I provided considers the whole line, extended infinitely. For your needs, I think you can check before if your centroid is outside of some "square" that encloses your line segment. (check if centroid x and y is outside x's and y's of your line segment)

Comment: in python, you can use things like `if x1 < x3 < x2` to chain comparisons. In this case, to check if x3 is between x1 and x2

Comment: Yes, Gustavo, I am using this now. I thought about the same. I very thankful to you for giving instant solution. Thank you so much. Let me check right now and I will get back to you after the final results.

Answer (score 1):

Let the line go from point `l0` to point `l1`. Then let the centroid be point `p1`. Let the vector `l` be the vector from `l0` to `l1` and `p` from `l0` to `p1`. Then you can find the distance from the point `p1` to the line using dot product as described [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/dot-product-distance-between-point-and-a-line/).

You probably want to find the distance from your point to the *line segment* and then evaluate if the point is on the line segment based on that distance. This can be done in a similar fashion but with more logic around it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment).

An implementation in python using `numpy` is given below. It can easily be extended to handle `N` centroids, enabling you to track different objects in parallel. It works by projecting the point onto the line segment and finding the distance from this point to the centroid.

```
import numpy as np

def distance_from_line_segment_points_to_point(l0, l1, p1):
    l0 = np.array(l0)
    l1 = np.array(l1)
    p1 = np.array(p1)

    l_vec = l1 - l0
    p_vec = p1 - l0

    if (l0 == l1).all():
        return np.linalg.norm(p_vec)

    l_norm = np.linalg.norm(l_vec)
    l_unit = l_vec / l_norm

    t = np.dot(l_unit, p_vec)
    if t >= l_norm:
        p_proj = l1
    elif t <= 0:
        p_proj = l0
    else:
        p_proj = l0 + t * l_unit
    return np.linalg.norm(p1 - p_proj)

print(distance_from_line_segment_points_to_point([0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 1]))  # sqrt(2), 1.4
print(distance_from_line_segment_points_to_point([0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1]))  # 1
print(distance_from_line_segment_points_to_point([0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]))  # sqrt(2)/2, 0.707
```